# How to pass variable content to dynamically created onclick function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, onclick

I'm trying to pass the contents of a variable into a dynamically altered `onclick` setting. The beginning of the code grabs the existing `onclick` information, converts it to a string, changes it around, and I'm trying to put it back in.

Problem is that it inserts the text of my variable name and not the content of the variable. The console log returns `ƒ () { onClickFill(ocstr); }`. The function I'm calling is a basic `location.href=(variable)`, so if there is a way to eliminate the additional function, I'm all for it. Thanks

Old:

```
var ocstr = b.onclick.toString();
ocstr = ocstr.replace(/to=.*/, tostr.slice(0, -1) + "';");
ocstr = ocstr.slice(43).slice(0,-4);
b.onclick = function () { onClickFill(ocstr); };
console.log(b.onclick);
```

New:

```
var ocstr = b.onclick.toString().replace(/to=.*/, tostr.slice(0, -1) + "';").slice(43).slice(0,-4);
b.onclick = new Function("location.href='" + ocstr + "'");
console.log(b.onclick);
```

Comment: Was able to play with code provided by Scott Marcus and even eliminate the additional function. I've edited original  post to include working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions that are dynamically created from strings are not built that way and are usually not-advised to be dynamically built with strings in the first place due to security and performance issues. Instead the parts of a function that may vary should be set up as arguments or conditional logic based on something.

But, it can be done with the **[`Function()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)**:

```
var ocstr = b.onclick.toString();
ocstr = ocstr.replace(/to=.*/, tostr.slice(0, -1) + "';");
ocstr = ocstr.slice(43).slice(0,-4);
b.onclick = new Function("function(){ onClickFill(ocstr) }");
console.log(b.onclick);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The issue I'm running into with this is that it executes immediately. Thoughts on preventing that?

Comment: @Josh What part do you want to defer and when do you want to defer it to?

Comment: The onclick function. Setting the new function is also executing it. I need it to wait until the button is actually clicked.

Comment: @Josh Ok, I've updated the answer for that. It wasn't clear that `onClickFill()` was the new function to be called when the button gets clicked. I thought it was some other function that returned a function to become the click callback.

Comment: Trying that, my Console Log returns:

VM508:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at eBox (collinsfunctions.js:348)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (dprsend.php?project=Welltown&year=2018&month=01&date=5&to=s****@c*******ricco.net:13)

Comment: @Josh That sounds more like a problem with what `onClickFill` is returning.

Comment: Was able to build on this and get something that works (edited question to include working code). Seems that the content of my variable, which was a url, was causing issues. Thanks for the help.